# Changing the <title> display in a Enterprise Wiki Publishing Site

Tags: publishing-site, sharepoint-enterprise

I'm trying to change the way a `<title>` displays. Currently it just displays the page name in most cases "Home". What I would like it to look like is "Site Collection Name - Page Name" It seems to work fine when I'm working with non-publishing sites and I noticed both use the same master page tag `<title id="onetidTitle"><asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/></title>`

So far the things I've tried:

1. Adding a title in the SharePoint Page Properties (<--Doesn't Show
   up anywhere)
2. Adding the title manually before the
   `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/>`
   (<-- Also didn't get recognized after publishing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also noticed that if you put some value before the placeholder in master page, it does not work. However, in your page template, if you put something like below, it will show title of the web and title of the page.

```
<asp:Content contentplaceholderid="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:ProjectProperty runat="server" id="ProjectProperty1" Property="Title" /> - <SharePoint:fieldvalue id="PageTitle" FieldName="Title" runat="server"/>
</asp:Content>
```

Please note that control shown above displays current web’s title, if you have to write a custom control.

Answer (score 1):

It is also possible, using an encoded literal. Like this:

```
<title id="onetidTitle">
    <SharePoint:EncodedLiteral runat="server" text="My Site" EncodeMethod='HtmlEncode' />
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server"/>
</title>
```